# Odd behaviour with varnishlog and stream redirecting

Tags: linux, centos, bash, command-line-interface, varnish

I wrote a helper to debug varnish installation and have used it on both production and development server. The odd thing is, I encountered different behaviour even though the setup is nearly identical (except hardware).

The command is:

```
varnishlog > /var/log/v1.log & curl -I $URL; kill $!
```

On our production server it works as expected: `varnishlog` starts as a background process and redirects it's output to `/var/log/v1.log` - then `curl` executes and when it's done `varnishlog` is killed (although I don't see the 'terminated' message until next command is executed).

On our development server, the command executes and 'terminated' message appears right after `crul`'s output. However, `/var/log/v1.log` is empty.

Both servers `uname -srvmo` returns `Linux 2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Aug 28 17:19:38 UTC 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux` and both are running `CentOS release 6.4 (Final)`.

**EDIT**: It seems that `varnishlog > /var/log/v1.log` doesn't work. Neither does `varnishlog > /var/log/v1.log 2>&1` or `varnishlog | tee /var/log/v1.log` (the latter does not product output to console either). Other commands (e.g. `echo 'test' > /var/log/v1.log`) work as expected. Varnish version is exactly the same on both machines (`varnish-3.0.5 revision 1a89b1f`).

Comment: Use parameter *-w file* to write log entries to file instead of displaying them. The file will be overwritten unless the -a option was specified.  https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/varnishlog.html

Comment: @masegaloeh Thanks, that's exactly what I ended up doing in the end to get the logs. Nonetheless, I'm still quite curious as to why this is occurring.